# Generating number sequence

Tags: integer-sequence

I am very new to mathematica. I am trying to generate list of number sequence.
I want to make 6 sequences. 1 - 10, 10 - 100, 100 - 1 000, 1 000 - 10 000, 10 000 - 100 000. All reversed. Is there any elegant to way how to approach that? I am trying to figure it out using documentation, but I can't. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [`Range`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html), i.e. something like this: `Range[10, 1, -1]`? You may also be interested in [`PowerRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerRange.html), and combine it with `Range`.

Comment: `seqs = Range[10^Range[0, 4], 10^Range[1, 5]]`. Then `seqs[[1]]` will be your first sequence, `seqs[[2]]` the second...
`Reverse/@seq` will reverse them.

`rseqs=Range[10^Range[1, 5], 10^Range[0, 4], -1]` will generate them already reversed.

Comment: `Table[Range[10^(n + 1), 10^n, -10^n], {n, 0, 4}]` Change the steps to `-1` if that is what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It helped me. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses a combination of [`Range`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html) and [`PowerRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerRange.html):

```
Reverse /@ Range @@@ Partition[PowerRange[100000], 2, 1]
```

Here is an example of output (shortened using `Shallow`):

```
{{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 
 {100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, <<81>>}, 
 {1000, 999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, <<891>>}, 
 {10000, 9999, 9998, 9997, 9996, 9995, 9994, 9993, 9992, 9991, <<8991>>}, 
 {100000, 99999, 99998, 99997, 99996, 99995, 99994, 99993, 99992, 99991, <<89991>>}, 
}
```